# Issue with adding Upload Handlers on the fly in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to add an upload handler on the fly following this [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/file-uploads/#upload-handlers) but receiving an error **You cannot alter upload handlers after the upload has been processed.**

Here's my `views.py`

```
# asset uploading view
# @login_required(login_url='login/')
@csrf_exempt
def upload_asset_view(request):
    request.upload_handlers.insert(0, S3FileUploadHandler())

    return _upload_asset_view(request)

@csrf_protect
def _upload_asset_view(request):
    # form has been uploaded POST
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadAssetForm(request.POST, request.FILES)

        if form.is_valid():
            # store asset
            asset = store_asset(form, request)

            # print zip file details
            # zip_data = print_zip_file_details('https://3d-configurator.s3.amazonaws.com/' + asset.file.name)
            # textures = print_zip_file_details('http://roombuilder.s3.amazonaws.com/staging_bbby_google_ar/bbby_automation_backend/items/bbby-gltf-assets/133549_18660083_GLTF.zip')

            # add message to sqs
            # sqs_response = add_message_to_sqs(asset)

            pprint('done')
            # return render(request, 'dashboard/list_zip_data.html', {
            #     'textures': textures,
            #     'filename': asset.file.name
            # })
        else:
            pprint('error')
            pprint(form.errors)

    # if GET, then get UploadAssetForm
    else:
        form = UploadAssetForm()

    return render(request, 'dashboard/form_upload_asset.html', {
        'form': form
    })
```

and here's my **template**

```
<form method="post" action="/" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

    <p class="lead">Please upload your zip file</p>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I have used both `csrf_exempt` and `csrf_protect` decorators but still can't seem to find what the error could be.

Comment: Maybe you have some other middleware specified in your `settings.py` that is modifying the `request.POST` or `request.FILES`?

Comment: Should I also share my `settings.py` file?

Comment: Yes I think that would be useful if you can.